# Create an array from JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, html-table, getjson

I've researched quite a bit on here and I can't seem to find something that will work for me.  What I have is an application that I'm trying to have go out and return the next four bus arrival times for a bus stop.  I am reaching out to an API that returns this data in a JSON file.  The problem I am having is I can see my request go out via fiddler but I can't seem to get the data into an array.  Below is the code that I'm dealing with right now.  I'm trying to get the returned data into a table format which you can see I'm failing at.

Eventually I want to get a popup to appear when the user clicks on the Show me the next 4 bus arrival times but this was for testing purposes.  I would love to have the users click on my button which calls this function and then something like a like table open with these values.  If you can help with that within this code I would appreciate it as well.

JSON Data:

```
[{"ARRIVAL":"01:23P","ROUTE":"208","DIR":"E"},
{"ARRIVAL":"01:53P","ROUTE":"208","DIR":"E"},
{"ARRIVAL":"02:23P","ROUTE":"208","DIR":"E"},
{"ARRIVAL":"02:53P","ROUTE":"208","DIR":"E"}]
```

Code:

```
<script>
function getTimes(stopNumber) {
        var busArrivalAPI = "http://blahblahblah/rtcTimes/" + stopNumber ";
        $.getJSON(busArrivalAPI, function(busArrivals) {
            var a = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < busArrivals.length; i++) {
                a[i] = [busArrivals[i].ROUTE, busArrivals[i].ARRIVAL, busArrivals[i].DIR];
                document.getElementById("results").createElement("TR");
                for (var b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                    var x = document.createElement("TH");
                    var z = a[i][b];
                    var t = document.createTextNode(z);
                    x.appendChild(t);
                    document.getElementById('results').appendChild(x);
                };
            };
        });     
</script>
```

My DIV:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:scroll;" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Bus Arrival Times', selected:true">
  <table id = 'results'>
    <tr>
      <th>Route</th>
      <th>Arrival Time</th>
      <th>Direction</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

UPDATE:  Ok, I've use the makeTable idea provide below and it works when I program as seen below hard coding the json data.  However, when trying to use the $.getJSON I'm having some cross domain issues now and don't know how I can get my $.getJSON request working.  Any input on how to get the data from my getJSON request work be great.

```
function getTimes(stopNumber) {

    // This is the API address I need to hit.  Trying to figure out how to incorporate that and remove the function getJSON where I have the data hard coded.
    //var busArrivalAPI = "http://-----/rtcTimes/"+ stopNumber + "?jsoncallback=?";    

    function makeTable(busArrivals) {
    // This will remove old values so table will only load current Times
      var results = document.getElementById("results");
      var rowCount = results.rows.length;
      for (var x=rowCount-1; x>0; x--) {
        results.deleteRow(x);
      }
      //  This will populate the result table with the correct bus routes/times/direction
      busArrivals.forEach(function(busArrival) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var route = document.createElement('td');
        route.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.ROUTE));
        var arrival = document.createElement('td');
        arrival.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.ARRIVAL));
        var direction = document.createElement('td');
        direction.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.DIR));
        tr.appendChild(route);
        tr.appendChild(arrival);
        tr.appendChild(direction);
        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(tr);
      });
    }

    function getJSON(callback) {
      var data = [{"ARRIVAL":"05:23P","ROUTE":"201","DIR":"E"},
        {"ARRIVAL":"05:54P","ROUTE":"202","DIR":"E"},
        {"ARRIVAL":"06:33P","ROUTE":"203","DIR":"E"},
        {"ARRIVAL":"07:11P","ROUTE":"204","DIR":"E"}];
        callback(data);
    }

    getJSON(makeTable);
  };
```

Comment: It would seem that your code is malformed. Your `getTimes` function is missing a closing `}`. Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: If this is a copy&past of you code then one of your problems is that you use `data.length`, `data[i].ROUTE` , ... but your parameter is `busArrivals`

Comment: Sorry, fixed } and fixed busArrivals.  Still doesn't work.  I know my table creation with all the <th> and <tr> doesn't work correctly but at this point I'm just trying to get something to show up.

Comment: You haven't fixed `busArrivals`. You're still using `data[i]` instead.

Comment: Actually, it's `data.length` that's still in use.

Comment: i do see an error here: var busArrivalAPI = "http://blahblahblah/rtcTimes/" + stopNumber "; // the quote in the end

Comment: Again I ask, are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Comment: You're never appending the `TR` to the table.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: No, no errors in console.  Yes I know I'm missing the </tr> stuff as well.

Comment: omg post valid code, people are finding so many errors in your code that it seems like you haven't even tried to solve this yourself. if you know there's a problem with what you've posted fix it or explain, otherwise how are we supposed to give good advice?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to ensure I had everything on their correctly.  I asked for patience and apologized in advance.  Seriously, if you don't want to help then don't.  I'm learning and appreciate all the comments I can get.  I did try to solve this myself over the past week. Yes, I posted the code with some errors as I have been trying different iterations and sorry it was wrong for the first 5 minutes it was posted.

Comment: @Johnny That extra comma (oddly, only in the final object) is the invalid portion of the JSON.

Comment: @PaulRoub - Sorry, once again I was editing the code to show only what I needed and this was left in there.

Comment: @Johnny The time needed to seek for syntax and naming errors, is not only missing to help others - thats what some complain about - but will also make it less likely that your actual problem will be solved. You might have luck like right now, that everybody is in a good mood, but you  just as easily could have only got down-votes. As of that the least thing you should do provide code that will have no syntax errors. And ideally no other error showing up in the console. If an error shows up you should mention that error in your question, to show that you are award of that error.

Comment: @t.niese  Thank you, much appreciate all the input I'm getting.  As you can see I'm not a big poster at all to the site, more of your browser for answers type of person.  I apologize again for not having this correct off the bat and after having read so many topics I was aware that negative comments or ratings were potentially in order.  I do appreciate all the input and patience.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could write a separate function to build the table, like this:

```
function makeTable(busArrivals) {
    busArrivals.forEach(function(busArrival) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        var route = document.createElement('td');
        route.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.ROUTE));
        var arrival = document.createElement('td');
        arrival.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.ARRIVAL));
        var direction = document.createElement('td');
        direction.appendChild(document.createTextNode(busArrival.DIR));
        tr.appendChild(route);
        tr.appendChild(arrival);
        tr.appendChild(direction);
        document.getElementById('results').appendChild(tr);
    });
}

var busArrivalAPI = 'http://blahblahblah/rtcTimes/'+ stopNumber;
$.getJSON(busArrivalAPI, makeTable);
```

In each iteration of the forEach loop, you construct a tr element, insert the tds and finally put the whole thing inside the DOM.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as well.  Thank you all for the continued input.  It's very much appreciated.

Comment: I like the idea you shared with me about the table.  I created that but I'm still not getting any data into the table.  Thank you for the input.

Comment: I now get data into the table.  I updated my post above with the issues that I'm now dealing with.  You can see that when I hard code the data it works great but when trying to use the $.getJSON I'm having issues with cross domain unless I'm using the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a `TR` element, but never appending it to the table. Instead, you're appending the `TH` elements directly to the table, which is invalid.

```
function getTimes(stopNumber) {
    var busArrivalAPI = "http://blahblahblah/rtcTimes/" + stopNumber;
    $.getJSON(busArrivalAPI, function(busArrivals) {
        var table = document.getElementById('results');
        for (var i = 0; i < busArrivals.length; i++) {
            var a = [busArrivals[i].ROUTE, busArrivals[i].ARRIVAL, busArrivals[i].DIR];
            var row = document.createElement("TR");
            for (var b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
                var x = document.createElement("TH");
                var z = a[b];
                var t = document.createTextNode(z);
                x.appendChild(t);
                row.appendChild(x);
            };
            table.appendChild(row);
        };
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why you need the `a` array. If you just want to change get the object properties into an array so you can iterate over it, you can do that with a 1-dimensional array, you don't need to save all the other rows in a 2-dimensional array. I've changed `a` to a single array.

Comment: I was trying to research a solution and somewhere I saw that they created this 'a' array in order to store the different values correctly from the array.  Again, not a high level or medium or low level programmer here just trying to learn.  Thank you for your input, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've updated the answer showing how to do it with just a single dimension.

Comment: I tried that out and I had to add the following in order to not get a crossdomain policy issue to my url string:  var busArrivalAPI = "http://----------m/rtcTimes/" + stopNumber + "?jsoncallback=?";   I think I may be off with this here but when I use the jsoncallback I don't get the crossdomain issues.

Comment: That's a totally separate issue.

Comment: Sorry.  Perhaps I Should simply delete this entire question of mine.  Seems as though I've opened up pandoras box of issues with the way I am approaching this needed solution.